# apt-get update Crashes

Tags: apt

I have just successfully done

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Success meaning they finished and no errors which stopped the process - I did get a warning about something to do with bluetooth - which I don't have, so I continued on

Now when I try to do

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It says

```
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease Hit:2
Hit:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease Reading
package lists...13%
```

(sometimes it say 12%)

The the raspberry hangs - in that pressing caps-lock no longer changes the capslock light and pressing ctl-c etc does nothing and the only way I can get back is by removing the power

Is there some way I can reset what-ever it is doing or do I have to rebuild my SD card again?

Comment: I cannot give a definitive answer - the process can take some time, and removing power only exacerbates any problem. You may have corrupt packages. You should ALWAYS make a backup BEFORE upgrading (this applies to all computers not just the Pi). If you can still boot try `sudo apt-get clean` to empty the cache.

Comment: Yes the machine boots, the first time. I waited around ten minutes but the percent complete did not change I have also left it overnight and it stayed on 13percent complete

Comment: @Milliways But why should a corrupt package cache cause the entire system to hang completely?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is something wrong with your package lists. You can try to rebuild them. The lists are located in `/var/lib/apt/lists`. With brute force you can delete them but I prefer to do it under control of the package system. For this you can edit all *sources.list* and comment all repositories in them so you have only empty (without repositories) *sources.list*.  By default you have:

```
rpi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi

rpi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
```

Comment the first line in them, save them and update the lists:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
```

This will purge the list files in `/var/lib/apt/lists`. Then remove the comment hashes you have just set and update again.

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt update
```

This will download all missing lists from the repositiories.

Comment: This seemed to work but I still had problems eventually I changed SD card  and machine , rebuilt and copied the customisation across.  The old one still won’t update although it is a different message.

Comment: @Ross That isn't in the question. So what have you done and what exactly is your problem after that?

Answer (score 0):

Answering a pretty old post here, but I figured my solution might help others like me who landed on this (and other SE) pages.

I had a similar issue on my Zero 2 W.  apt-get update would get a certain percentage through some step, and my SSH session would freeze (along with any other SSH sessions I might have open to the same Raspberry Pi).

I solved it by increasing the swap file size.  I had tried many other suggestions from others, eg. disable IPv6, run fsck, and use raspi-config to disable bootup to GUI (since I'm using it headless anyway).  I believe that only Disabling startup to GUI was useful - it stopped my SSH sessions locking up completely, allowing me to keep a second SSH session open and monitor resources with htop (although htop itself was still freezing occasionally for up to 30 seconds at a time when the Pi's CPU was really busy with apt-get operations).

htop showed me that system memory was pretty heavily utilised to begin with, then being maxed out by apt-get related processes, spilling over into heavy swapfile use, maxing out the meagre 100 MB which is the default.  So I changed the swapfile size from the default 100 MB to 1024 MB, and my problem was resolved.  It probably doesn't need to be as high as 1024 MB, I just chose that value so as to make a definitively large change, to see if it solved the issue.  I have plenty of spare SD space so I'm going to leave it at 1 GB.

Link for how to change the swap size: https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-swap-file/

Hope that helps others :)